# How to get the resources with an outlook 365 appointment?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office365api

I'm creating an app for outlook 365 with the office.js API.
[Microsoft documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html) stated that its possible to get the resources.
But the Office.context.mailbox.item has to be an appointment item and in readmode.

The appointment is no problem, but how to set the item in readmode? Is it even possible to view an appointment in readmode?

Answer (score 0):

Office.js API documentation on enumeration [Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.MailboxEnums.html#.ItemType) has listed 2 type only: one is Appointment item, which is item in edit mode by organizer; second is Message, which everything else, including not just e-mails, but meeting request, meeting response, or meeting cancellation. Is this what you probably called "appointment in read mode". Of cause as any Message item you have access to properties (you called it "resources") of this item via Office.js API for [Office.context.mailbox.item](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html).

Comment: No, he is really talking about the 'Resources' of an appointment. Currently it is still impossible (after a few yers) to get the selected 'Resources'/Rooms of an appointment in the Outlook app. (see https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/186 and https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13316001-add-office-javascript-api-support-for-resources-of). In the WebApp it is working fine, because there there is no special 'Resources' field, but a resource/room is added as a required attendee! Has anyone have a workaround for this?